# "Same" network on MATLAB and Keras has very different results

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to replicate the same simple network structure in MATLAB and Keras. The problem is the accuracy I get is very different. MATLAB code gets accuracy near 0.84 and loss near 17 and Keras code gets accuracy near 0.63 and loss near 130, with Keras using double epochs to train and the same data. I think the difference is too big to be a matter of implementation, so I think I'm missing something.

The original code is from a MATLAB example in which I have made a little change to avoid normalization in the first layer.

Here is the MATLAB code:

```matlab
% Load the digit training set as 4-D array data using
% |digitTrain4DArrayData|.
[trainImages,~,trainAngles] = digitTrain4DArrayData;

disp("Train Images:")
disp(trainImages(:,:,:,1))
% Display 20 random sample training digits using |imshow|.
numTrainImages = size(trainImages,4);

figure
idx = randperm(numTrainImages,20);
for i = 1:numel(idx)
    subplot(4,5,i)

    imshow(trainImages(:,:,:,idx(i)))
    drawnow
end

%%
% Combine all the layers together in a |Layer| array.
layers = [ ...
    imageInputLayer([28 28 1], 'Normalization', 'none')
    convolution2dLayer(12,25)
    reluLayer
    fullyConnectedLayer(1)
    regressionLayer];

%% Train Network'

options = trainingOptions('sgdm','InitialLearnRate',0.001, ...
    'MaxEpochs',15)

net = trainNetwork(trainImages,trainAngles,layers,options)

net.Layers

%% Test Network
[testImages,~,testAngles] = digitTest4DArrayData;

predictedTestAngles = predict(net,testImages);

% *Evaluate Performance*
predictionError = testAngles - predictedTestAngles;

thr = 10;
numCorrect = sum(abs(predictionError) < thr);
numTestImages = size(testImages,4);

accuracy = numCorrect/numTestImages

%%
% Use the root-mean-square error (RMSE) to measure the differences between
% the predicted and actual angles of rotation.
squares = predictionError.^2;
rmse = sqrt(mean(squares))

%%
% *Display Box Plot of Residuals for Each Digit Class*
residuals = testAngles - predictedTestAngles;

residualMatrix = reshape(residuals,500,10);

figure
boxplot(residualMatrix, ...
    'Labels',{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'})

xlabel('Digit Class')
ylabel('Degrees Error')
title('Residuals')

idx = randperm(numTestImages,49);
for i = 1:numel(idx)
    image = testImages(:,:,:,idx(i));
    predictedAngle = predictedTestAngles(idx(i));

    imagesRotated(:,:,:,i) = imrotate(image,predictedAngle,'bicubic','crop');
end

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
montage(testImages(:,:,:,idx))
title('Original')

subplot(1,2,2)
montage(imagesRotated)
title('Corrected')
```

Here is the Keras code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, AveragePooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import regularizers

np.random.seed(1671) # for reproducibility
# network and training
NB_EPOCH = 30
BATCH_SIZE = 128
VERBOSE = 1
NB_CLASSES = 10 # number of outputs = number of digits
OPTIMIZER = SGD() # SGD optimizer, explained later in this chapter
N_HIDDEN = 128
VALIDATION_SPLIT=0.2 # how much TRAIN is reserved for VALIDATION

data = scipy.io.loadmat('RegressionImageData.mat')

XTrain = np.rollaxis(data['XTrain'],3,0)
XTest = np.rollaxis(data['XTest'],3,0)
YTest = np.squeeze(data['YTest'])
YTrain = np.squeeze(data['YTrain'])

print("Train Images:")
print(XTrain.shape)
print(type(XTrain))
print(XTrain)

XTrain_test = np.reshape(XTrain, (5000,28,28))

with open("./test.txt", "a+") as file:
    np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
    file.write(np.array2string(XTrain_test[0], max_line_width=np.inf))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(25,(12,12), input_shape=(28,28,1), strides=(1,1), activation = "relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.summary()

sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=0.1, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)

history = model.fit(XTrain, YTrain,
batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=NB_EPOCH,
verbose=VERBOSE, validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT,
shuffle=False)

predictions= model.predict(XTrain)
[np.transpose(predictions[1:50]), np.transpose(YTrain[1:50]), np.abs(np.transpose(predictions[1:50])- np.transpose(YTrain[1:50]))]

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('rmse')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

Ypred_test= model.predict(XTest)
Ypred_test=np.reshape(Ypred_test, (5000,))
predictionError = Ypred_test - YTest
thr = 10;
numCorrect = np.sum((np.abs(predictionError) < thr)*1)
numValidationImages = len(YTest)

accuracy = numCorrect/numValidationImages
print(accuracy)
squares = np.power(predictionError,2)
rmse = np.sqrt(np.mean(squares))
print(rmse)
```

Anyone know where could be the gap?

Comment: Have you tried with `decay=0.0` (default value) for the `SGD` optimizer in Keras?

Comment: And further, the weight initialization of layers might be different. For example, by default the `glorot_uniform` (i.e. uniform distribution) is used for kernel initialization of `Dense` layer in Keras, whereas in MATLAB Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 0.01 is used for initializing weights of `fullyConnectedLayer`.

Comment: I have tried with decay=0.0 pero with that value Keras got worse results (0.2 accuracy). I have tried to force the same initialization in MATLAB and Keras (gaussian distribution with mean 0 and standard desviation 0.01) in convolutional and dense layer. MATLAB had good results (accuracy near 0.8), Keras had worse results (accuracy near 0.25).

Comment: I am facing the same problem, were you able to find the reason behind this discrepancy? @JorgeGarcía